# Prove that $\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)^2\ge{(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\in{\mathbb{R^+}}$. Prove that

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)^2\ge{(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)}$$

I tried to expand both, but I did not get anything useful.

Comment: Have you tried using Rearrangement Inequality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On expanding, this is the same as showing
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \right) +\left(\frac{b}a+\frac{a}c+\frac{c}b\right)\ge \left(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a\right)+3$$
which follows using a series of AM-GMs.  Specifically:
$$\begin{align}
LHS &\ge \left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \right) +3 \\
&= \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+1 \right) \ge \sum_{cyc}2\frac{a}b \\
&\ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}b+3 = RHS
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

As Macavity says, this is the same as
$$
\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \right) +\left(\frac{b}a+\frac{a}c+\frac{c}b\right)\ge \left(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a\right)+3
$$
which is the same after rearrangement as
$$
\underbrace{\left(\frac ab-1\right)^2+\left(\frac bc-1\right)^2+\left(\frac ca-1\right)^2}_{\ge0}
\ge\underbrace{6-\left(\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca\right)-\left(\frac ba+\frac ac+\frac cb\right)}_{\le0}
$$
since $x+\frac1x\ge2$.